# What is MTU on a network adapter and what problems can wrong MTU cause?

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

What is the MTU value on a network interface, and how does its value impact a network? How can I check what it is and change it? How can you tell what MTU a network operates on?

Comment: I'd perhaps suggest an extension to this: Is there any way to find out what the network (local and WAN) *supports*?

Comment: @Oli since MTU checks don't pass between each device hop, you'd have to connect to each hop in the network between inside and outside individually.  The vast majority of common place network setups (Verizon FiOS, Comcast Cable Business, Spectrum hi-speed/coax, etc.) operate on 1500 bytes, and only in *very* specific circumstances are they larger or smaller.  L3 has MTU and *everything* in the Ethernet network has to talk the same MTU - if there are components with mismatched MTUs there's larger problems in the network so changing the MTU is never a first resort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MTU, or Max Transmission Unit, is the maximum *payload* that can be transmitted over a interface. The payload includes any L3 headers, such as TCP/IP, but excludes layer 2 headers, such as the Ethernet frame header.

In the case of Ethernet, the MTU is commonly 1500 bytes. This means that the TCP/IP packet can be up to 1500 bytes. In addition, there's a Ethernet frame header, so the total Ethernet frame is 1518 bytes as travelling over the wire. With a VLAN tag, this increases to 1522B with a MTU of 1500B.

## Common MTU values

For home networks, 1500B is the common value for both Wi-Fi and Ethernet. While the frame is different on Wi-Fi and Ethernet, both are capable of handling a 1500B payload. The [maximum for Wi-Fi is 2304B](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/what-is-the-802-11-mtu). For Ethernet the largest *common* size is 9000B, but larger may be used.

**Generally, the MTU will be 1500B in Wi-Fi and Ethernet networks, and this should *not* be changed unless there's compelling reasons to do so - as changing the MTU breaks expected behavior.**

PPPoE is a common exception; as PPPoE runs on top of Ethernet, it has to fit in the 1500B frames of Ethernet. The header of PPPoE is 8 bytes, so the useable MTU is 1492B. Note that your local network can run on 1500B MTU even though Internet connection is at 1492B MTU, thanks to path MTU discovery. If a majority of traffic is towards Internet, you *can* lower MTU, but will not gain significantly by doing so, and may break things in the process because equipment *expects* MTU to be 1500B.

## What problems can be caused by wrong MTU setting

### Different MTU in same network

Frames that are larger than the MTU will be silently discarded by the network card. If you have dissimilar MTU, this means that one host may send frames that other hosts on the network can't receive. The behavior can be strange.

For instance logins and ssh may work fine, as ssh sends many small packets to reduce latency, but scp may fail because scp uses larger packets as it transmits a file, not screen content or keypresses and doesn't have to wait for data. Tools such as `ping` will probably not indicate errors as well with default payload size.

It can also be expirienced that connections works in one direction, but not the other. SCP may work when copying data from host A to host B, but fail when attempting to copy from host B to host A.

The consequence is that MTU mismatch can be hard to diagnose if you don't recognize the symptoms and are paranoid enough to check and verify the MTU settings...

Every computer on the same broadcast segment should have the same MTU setting. This includes situations where there's different access technologies in the same L2 system, for instance WiFi and Ethernet.

### How can you find the MTU for a network?

You can't. There's no mechanism in Layer 2 Ethernet to report MTU. If the packet is too large, it's not received by the recipient - but the lack of reply *can* have other reasons apart from wrong MTU.

As admin, you have to ensure that all devices on the same Layer 2 segment has the same MTU setting. This should *always* be 1500 bytes for Ethernet and WiFi, unless you have reasons for a different setting.

Between networks (e.g. where packets are routed), you can discover path MTU using `tracepath example.org` - but this will only tell you what hosts *believe* they can use. If a host is wrongly configured, it will fail.

### MTU changes between networks

Where networks change transport interfaces, MTU changesmay happen. One case where this happens is the ADSL interfaces with PPPoE. As Ethernet has 1500B payload, and PPP eats 8 bytes, we end up with 1492B payload on the PPPoE interface. In this case the break happens at a routed interface, so TCP/IP packets can be fragmented, or Path MTU discovery will adjust the Maximum Segment Size, which is a related concept for TCP/IP.

If an too large packet is received and to be forwarded to an interface it can't fit on, one of two things can happen:

1. If the [Don't Fragment bit (DF) (IPv4)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61043/why-the-ipv4-need-dont-fragment-flag) is set, it will be dropped and the sender will be made aware of that it's too big.
2. If the DF is not set, the packet will be fragmented and sent as two fragments.

With the break in MTU created by PPPoE, it's at a routed boundary. The PPP interface created from the PPP link is *not* in the same L2 domain as any Ethernet interface.

#### What's Path MTU Discovery

[PMTUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery) is a technique for discovering the MTU of a given path. Note that it relies in ICMP, which may be blocked on some networks.

Path MTU detection will however not work if different devices on the same network have differing MTU values. It relies on devices receiving a packet with the Don't Fragment bit set, but too large to fit over target link. However, if there's a mismatch, it may fit on the target link - but not to be received by the destination if the destination has a lower MTU.

#### What's MSS?

Maximum Segment Size is a field in the TCP/IP header. It specifies how large *payload* is allowed, and holds an function related to MTU. It is however not MTU.

In addition TCP/IP has mechanisms for adjusting MSS. It can vary depending on communication partner, and can vary for the same TCP/IP stream.

#### What can set MTU?

Broadly speaking three things can set MTU on physical interfaces:

1. Standard setting, e.g. 1500B for Ethernet and Wi-Fi
2. User changes default
3. DHCP or IPv6 RA sets MTU

It can not be set dynamically depending on communication partner.

## MTU on Linux

While this is written for Ubuntu, this is common to all Linux modern Linux distros.

The command `ip link` can be used to show the MTU:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here we can see that MTU of the loopback interface is 65536B, and 1500B for `enp0s31f6`, which is a Ethernet interface.

It can be set using `ip link set dev <interface> mtu <value>`, where `<interface>` is the interface name. `ip link set dev enp0s31f6 mtu 1400` would set the MTU of `emp0s31f6` to 1400 bytes.

### Should I change it?

Generally speaking, no. If you need to change it you're probably aware of how to do it, and why you need to do it. The main case would be to increase it for high speed networks, such as 10Gb Ethernet and faster.

I've worked with networks for a number of years, and I have yet to see a general purpose network with a MTU not set to 1500B. The value is too well entrenched on Ethernet and Wi-Fi, and changing it outside specialized environments such as Data center networks will break with expected behavior.

## Jumbo Frames

With the advent of higher network speeds, the overhead from inter-frame-space and header has became more notable. Common size in such cases are 9000B MTU, and this [may be required to reach line speeds](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-get-maximum-throughput-100-gb-ethernet-adapter-non-virtualized-environment).

Other sizes are in use as well for various special purposes, to accomodate payloads such as MLPS or match page size in virtualized systems. This however falls in the category of specialized networks.

(Note: I'm aware of the fact that Ethernet is generally specified in Octets, not bytes. However, one byte = one octet. I've used byte in this answer, to avoid confusion.)

Comment: An MTU of 1600 is also relatively common in some types of Ethernet networks because it’s required to support running IP/MPLS over Ethernet (common in carrier networks). I’ve also seen 4096 talked about on occasion in virtualization contexts for purely software-based networks, as that translates to each packet being one page on x86 systems (which in turn is as big as you can get without adding more overhead).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Valid point. I would however argue that people know when they should use jumbo frames, and what size should be used - but I will add it :)

Comment: 9000 is also common with jumbo frames.

Comment: @SimonRichter jumbo frames is not the standard though.  In either case, Jumbo Frames exists for a *specific* environment need, and the vast majority of environments doesn't need jumbo frames to work.

Comment: To support the "Should I change it argument", see my question i asked to spotcheck sanity on MTU *recently* for a client's ~~incompetent~~ IT staff on Network engineering: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83458/sanity-check-changing-mtu-on-wifi-endpoints-computers-should-be-a-last-resort (which even quotes that changing it SHOULD NOT BE NECESSARY except in very specific circumstances the vast majority of which are *not in the average network use case*.)

Comment: `tracepath` (`sudo apt install tracepath`) is a tool for discovering PMTU.

Comment: The `tracepath` and `tracepath6` discover Path MTU using UDP packets. `tcptraceroute` can discover Path MTU using TCP packets.